# Why after I added a JComboBox into one of the JPanels, all JPanels were not rendered

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

When the `JComboBox`, `cmbox` was not added to a `JPanel`, two panels, `p1` & `p2` could be rendered. You may comment out the combo box portion to see the result. But after I added the combo box into one of the panels, all panels were not rendered.

My code is like the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCombo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("康樂彩歌");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("加簡譜", false);
        rb1.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
        rb2.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        rb1.setBounds(450, 180, 50, 50);
        rb2.setBounds(500, 180, 50, 50);

        JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));
        btPlay.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 20);//x axis, y axis, width, height  

        JButton btStop = new JButton("STOP");
        btStop.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));
        btStop.setBounds(140, 20, 100, 20);//x axis, y axis, width, height 

        //p1.add(cmbox);
        p1.add(rb1);
        p1.add(rb2);
        p1.add(btPlay);
        p1.add(btStop);
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();  //The JComboBox to be added to a JPanel
        cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
        cmbox.addItem("走一同去郊遊");
        cmbox.addItem("大野狼");
        cmbox.addItem("歸來吧蘇連多");
        cmbox.addItem("追尋");
        cmbox.addItem("三輪車");
        cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");
        cmbox.addItem("漁家樂");
        cmbox.addItem("嚕啦啦");
        cmbox.addItem("踏雪尋梅");

        p2.add(cmbox);

        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please use a descriptive name for test code. In this case, `Text` could be `TestCombo` 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) I've edited to do both those things, **this time.** In future I'll simply vote down and to close. It's your responsibility to provide a question with easy to read / use code, not the responsibility of anyone else.

Comment: 4) `btPlay.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 20);` Do not set the bounds of components. Let the layouts (padding and borders) do their job. 5) `frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 500);` That's just a guess, and if it's the right guess on one OS, it will be the wrong guess on others. Instead `pack()` the window after components are added. 6) I see the panels either way, if the combo box is added or not. But only after resizing the frame. Setting the frame visible should be the last thing done (& directly after the call to `pack()`). 7) Sidebar: GUIs should be started on the EDT.

Comment: 8) But for everything done wrong in the code above, you did one important thing **right.** By adding code that was compilable, I could quickly run it in my IDE, and check that the changes suggested would fix the problem, and there was nothing I had missed.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! As you may see my coding level, just a beginner in GUI, I will study more details on your code and instructions. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the changes as detailed below the code, solves the problem.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCombo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("康樂彩歌");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("加簡譜", false);
        rb1.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
        rb2.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

        JButton btStop = new JButton("STOP");
        btStop.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

        p1.add(rb1);
        p1.add(rb2);
        p1.add(btPlay);
        p1.add(btStop);
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();  //The JComboBox to be added to a JPanel
        cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
        cmbox.addItem("走一同去郊遊");
        cmbox.addItem("大野狼");
        cmbox.addItem("歸來吧蘇連多");
        cmbox.addItem("追尋");
        cmbox.addItem("三輪車");
        cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");
        cmbox.addItem("漁家樂");
        cmbox.addItem("嚕啦啦");
        cmbox.addItem("踏雪尋梅");

        p2.add(cmbox);

        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

1. `btPlay.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 20);` Do not set the bounds of components. Let the layouts (padding and borders) do their job.
2. `frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 500);` That's just a guess, and if it's the right guess on one OS, it will be the wrong guess on others. Instead `pack()` the window after components are added.
3. Sidebar: GUIs should be started on the EDT. (Not implemented above: 'batteries not included'.)

Comment: I don't know why when I tried to add p2, a second JPanel(MyPanel) with a moving square moving inside this JPanel, error showed up. p2.x = 50;
  p2.y = 100;
  p2.width = 50;
  p2.height = 50;
  
  //int i;
  //for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
   //System.out.println("i = " + i);
   //System.out.println("p2.x = " + p2.x);
   while(true ){
    p2.display();
    try {
     Thread.sleep(300); 
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
     e.printStackTrace();}
    }
   
   }
  
  
  frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: The very last three lines of the above code appear as errors.